# Tricking Oven to ignore intermittent door latch fault

Tags: oven

I have a Kitchenaid Superba oven/range that gives an intermittent door latch fault, which then shuts off the oven completely in all modes (convection, conduction, etc.).  Unfortunately a replacement door latch mechanism is no longer available.  Is there a way to fool the circuit board into thinking the latch is fine (perhaps bypassing the latch and wiring in resistors?).  I don't need latch functionality.  Thanks.

Model: KGST307HBS6

I have added stock images of the latch, per the helpful comment to investigate the lock mechanism.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the part number of the latch? Just because that part number is discontinued, doesn't mean the is not a replacement. Many times newer parts come out that replace the original. You might have to look at after market part and not OEM?

Comment: If that's a microwave oven, bypassing the latch can get someone killed one day.

Comment: @Agent_L It is a gas range.

Comment: @agent_l citation? Burned, irradiated, ok, but killed?

Comment: Part number AP3178818;  Website: 
https://www.appliancepartspros.com/whirlpool-oven-lock-assembly-9782611-ap3178818.html  There is no replacement

Comment: That is not the oem part number, that the the parts site part number. You will have to get the part number from the latch assembly on you oven.

Comment: If you look closely at the pic, it says whirlpool, try looking for a whirlpool latch with the same specs as yours, again, you need to get the info from the part in your door

Comment: I didn't post all part numbers, but the original Whirlpool number is #9782611.  Searching for any and all numbers yields no replacement.

Comment: That latch is potentially critical to avoid burns from opening the oven during self-cleaning. If you ever use the self-cleaning cycle then disabling/bypassing the latch is *not a good idea*.

Answer (score 2):

If I am not mistaken there is a [microswitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miniature_snap-action_switch) visible in the picture at the top, if that has gone bad (which is likely) then specifically that microswitch can be easily bought and replaced - they are a standard component which are used in many applications and are widely available.

[image]

If you must bypass it (not recommended) then you only need to short the relevant terminals.

Answer (score 1):

As an update, a few months ago, I pulled the oven to investigate.  Turns out the door locking rod was disconnected from the servo mechanism, so I think what happened was the following:

1. Door locked on previous owner and could not be opened
2. Previous owner (or technician) disconnected rod so it couldn't happen again (disabling cleaning function)
3. Years later, another fault began surfacing with the latch (as described above)
4. I replaced the latch (found on Ebay) and connected the rod, although the switch needs slight adjustment because the door isn't quite registering as locked (clean function will not start and get error code), but other error code is gone (so I'm happy).
5. Next time I pull the oven, I'll adjust the lock switch. (not a priority)

Answer (score 0):

You should investigate the mechanism of the door latch. Very often these have adjustments for switch or sensor position  to accommodate variation in manufactured parts.

Many times the open and closing of the door over a period of time can cause the mechanism to get out of adjustment. In the case of a detect switch it may have its switch point change after many cycles.